# Qt Axis implementation

Tags: c++, qt, plot

I am trying to implement a widget that draws an axis for a plot. What is the best way to implement this? I have several ideas in mind:

1. Inherit the `QWidget` class and override `paintEvent` and match the size of the axis widget to the plot.
2. Draw the axis in the `paintEvent` method of the plot class.

(The plot class does not inherit from `QCharts` so the `QAbstractAxis` cannot be used)

Comment: use QGraphicsView and do what is in QChartView.

Comment: search "chart" in Qt _examples_ shipped with QT .. even searching "Axis" gives you some examples.